# HTML element shows only after input is entered into prompt

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am writing very simple JavaScript codes to replace the `h1` heading by entering a new heading into a prompt. I don't understand why the original heading doesn't show when the page is first loaded. Only after I enter a new heading into the prompt, the heading will show. I already placed the script tag at the end of the body. What did I do wrong? I did get the original heading "Hello World" logged on console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Playing with the DOM</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 id="main-heading">Hello World</h1> 
    </div>
    <script>
      var headingElement = document.getElementById('main-heading');
      console.log(headingElement.innerHTML);
      var newHeadingText = prompt('Please provide a new heading');
      headingElement.innerHTML = newHeadingText;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's how browsers work. The HTML in `body` is parsed in the order it appears, when ever a script is met, it is also parsed and executed. Then parsing the rest of the HTML continues. Finally, all the elements get parsed, and browser knows what to show, and the page is actually rendered.

Comment: @Teemu I think you actually wanted to say "that's *how Chrome browser* works" because there is no reason for browser to stop rendering part of the page that is *before* the script... IE, Edge and FF show page just fine (now whether it is useful behavior or not is separate discussion, and real pages unlikely hit such scenario)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, I noticed that too, but it was too late to fix the comment, though some older IEs are waiting for the blocking scripts too, and sometimes FF too, maybe depends on caching ...

Comment: scabiosa - it is ok to post your own solution as an answer, but editing question with answer is against SO guidelines (as question is no longer question after such edit) - so I rolled back your edit. It is also bad idea to post link-only answer as you did (please check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). If you need to discuss my rollback - make sure to post clarifying question on https://meta.stackoverflow.com tagging "specific-question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hacky way and works not every time (looks like it's a Chrome feature), but you can add both `DOMContentLoaded` listener and empty `setTimeout`, it will let the DOM to be fully loaded before script execution:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var headingElement = document.getElementById('main-heading');
    var newHeadingText = prompt('Please provide a new heading');
    headingElement.innerHTML = newHeadingText;
  })
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="main-heading">Hello World</h1> 
</div>
```

Example with jQuery `document.ready`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var headingElement = document.getElementById('main-heading');
    var newHeadingText = prompt('Please provide a new heading');
    headingElement.innerHTML = newHeadingText;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 id="main-heading">Hello World</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: @scabiosa, notice, that it works most times, but not every time! Be careful ;)

Comment: How come this does not work? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var headingElement = document.getElementById('main-heading');
var newHeadingText = prompt('Please provide a new heading');
headingElement.innerHTML = newHeadingText;
});

Comment: @scabiosa, no, it works, but if you will test the snippet for example 20 times, may be one time the default `<h1>` will not be rendered before the alert will be shown.

Comment: I tested many times and not getting even once that it works :( . So is using jQuery more reliable in this situation?

Comment: @scabiosa, if you will follow this way, you can play around with `setTimeout` delay to make sure, that `<h1>` will be rendered before alert box. You can use it like this: `setTimeout(function() { // code here }, delay)`. Where I wrote `delay`, you can specify the delay in milliseconds.

Comment: @scabiosa, I have added an example with jQuery as well, you can try to test it.

Comment: @scabiosa, both `$(document).ready` with empty `setTimeout` looks OK in my Chrome ;)

Comment: @scabiosa, Ah, no, the same thing =(

Comment: @scabiosa, yeah? that's sounds great, may be the issue only in the snippet